# Weight converter not working with anything else than the first value

Tags: javascript, converters

I am building a weight converter with the help of bootstrap 4 and vanilla javascript. For the moment I managed to only transform pounds into everything else, not being able to select what to specifically transform to, just outputting everything right off the bat.
I also want to be able too choose from the units I am changing from and into. So far i have the values needed to change from pounds to everything else listed, and the same for kg.

Is there a way to display just a specific unit? For example, pounds to kg?
Is there a way to make this work?

Below are my html and js codes. Everything that is commented out of the js file is what i tried but didnt work out, and what remains is the functioning code, although incomplete/not doing what i want it to do.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- <div class="col-md-3"></div> -->

        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-3">
                Weight Converter
            </h1>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>From</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="weightSelector" function="elementSelect">
                        <option value="selectOption" disabled selected hidden>--- Please select ---</option>
                      <option value="tonne">Tonne</option>
                      <option value="kilogram">Kilogram</option>
                      <option value="gram">Gram</option>
                      <option value="milligram">Milligram</option>
                      <option value="ounces">Ounces</option>
                      <option value="stone">Stone</option>
                      <option value="pound">Pound</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
            </form> 
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>to</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="weightSelector" >
                        <option value="resultOption" disabled selected hidden>--- Please select ---</option>
                      <option value="tonne">Tonne</option>
                      <option value="kilogram">Kilogram</option>
                      <option value="gram">Gram</option>
                      <option value="milligram">Milligram</option>
                      <option value="ounces">Ounces</option>
                      <option value="stone">Stone</option>
                      <option value="pound">Pound</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
            </form>
            <form>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter your value" id="weightInput">
                </div>
            </form>

                <div id="output">
                    <div class="card bg-primary mb-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>grams</h4>
                            <div id="gramsOutput"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card bg-success mb-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>kg</h4>
                            <div id="kgOutput"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card bg-danger mb-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>Ounces</h4>
                            <div id="ozOutput"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card bg-primary mb-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>Tonne</h4>
                            <div id="tOutput"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card bg-success mb-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>miligrams</h4>
                            <div id="mgOutput"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card bg-danger mb-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>Stone</h4>
                            <div id="stOutput"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card bg-primary mb-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>Pound</h4>
                            <div id="lbsOutput"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="col-md-3"></div> -->
    </div>


</div>


document.getElementById('output').style.visibility='hidden';
// if i dont add the select forms and the functions to change to a
```

specific unit, it works, so basically this chunk of text

```
/*function elementSelect(){
var ddl=document.getElementById('weightSelector');
var selectedValue=ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;//this gets the 
element that is selected
if(selectedValue=="pound"){

    pound();
}
elseif(selectedValue=="kilogram"){
    kg();
}
 };
```

document.getElementById('weightSelector').addEventListener('click',elementSelect());*/

```
/*function pound(){
document.getElementById('weightInput').addEventListener('input',function(e){

document.getElementById('output').style.visibility='visible';


let lbs=e.target.value;
document.getElementById('gramsOutput').innerHTML=lbs/0.0022046;
document.getElementById('kgOutput').innerHTML=lbs/2.2046;
document.getElementById('ozOutput').innerHTML=lbs*16;
document.getElementById('mgOutput').innerHTML=lbs*453592.37;
document.getElementById('stOutput').innerHTML=lbs/14;
document.getElementById('tOutput').innerHTML=lbs/2204.623;
document.getElementById('lbsOutput').innerHTML=lbs;


 })
}

function kg(){

document.getElementById('weightInput').addEventListener('input',function(e){

document.getElementById('output').style.visibility='visible';


let kg=e.target.value;
document.getElementById('gramsOutput').innerHTML=kg*1000;
document.getElementById('kgOutput').innerHTML=kg;
document.getElementById('ozOutput').innerHTML=kg*35.274;
document.getElementById('mgOutput').innerHTML=kg*1e+6;
document.getElementById('stOutput').innerHTML=kg/6.35;
document.getElementById('tOutput').innerHTML=kg/1000;
document.getElementById('lbsOutput').innerHTML=kg*2.205;


})
```

}
   */

Comment: `('click',elementSelect())` should be `('click',elementSelect)`. You're calling `elementSelect` and using it's return value as a click handler, instead of using `elementSelect` as a click handler.

Comment: **You cannot have more than one element in a page with `id="weightSelector"`.** Use CSS classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Using The id Attribute
>
> The `id` attribute specifies a **unique** id for an HTML element (the value ***must*** be **unique** within the HTML document).
>
> ### Difference Between Class and ID
>
> An HTML element can only have one **unique** id that **belongs** to that single element, while a class name can be used by **multiple** elements [...]
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp

Because of this, `documentGetElementById()` will always only return the **first** element in a page with the id passed. Do not work around that, but fix it.